# Is there built in validation functions in CodeIgniter? That's NOT for forms

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I want to check if the variable `$username` is alphanumeric and less than 15 characters. Does CodeIgniter have this functionality built in? I don't want to rewrite these functions if they already exist. I know there's form validation, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Why not `$_POST['username'] = $username; run_CI_form_validation(); profit();`? - BTW, if you don't see the joke: You can read the source-code of CI. Check the validations you know, look if they use other components you can re-use, too.

Comment: Have you already tried simply passing a variable into the standard validation function?

Comment: You can also go manual....if(ctype_alnum($username) && in_array(strlen($username),range(3,15)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Sparky's comment, all the validation functions look like they are public functions inside of `Form_validation.php`

you can load form vlaidation and use the validation functions directly

so you could run it through [`max_length`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L1070) then [`alpha_numeric`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L1227), as they are all public just look at source and call them with the correct params

Comment: You're right `$this->form_validation->max_length('wut', 5);` works. Very cool.

Comment: I've been able to find everything in the CodeIgniter documentation so far. So I quickly assumed it wasn't possible without hacking.